# Can't find jack type for YFS201 sensor

Tags: identification, connector, flow-sensor

The [YFS201](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/yf-s201_sea.pdf) sensor comes with a unique connector (male) type for which I can't find the suitable female. Can someone tell what connector this is? Image can be found in [this](https://robu.in/product/yf-s201-water-flow-measurement-sensor-with-1-30liter-min-flow-rate-2/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwteOaBhDuARIsADBqRegQC1cKMv_0ZA8DD4HbF9QFc0XFRWJuJNqXCfNuQ4HL_hgd12jnpGYaAsHpEALw_wcB) link.

[image]

Comment: It doesn’t look too unique. Contact the supplier and ask them for a mating connector. No use asking Jack as he knows jack. Without any physical reference its difficult to determine dimensions but the pitch looks like 0.1”

Comment: @Kartman ok, I thought maybe someone would've used it and would know. Will contact the manufacturer

Comment: @DribbleNibble That's the usual way to go. Just ask the manufacturer. It's better to start there and, if no useful responses, then post here. But afterwards. Best wishes!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears to be a JST SM series (2.50mm pitch) rectangular housing. Scaling from [this](https://bc-robotics.com/shop/liquid-flow-meter/) image (Canadian dime is 18.03mm dia) agrees with the pitch. Eg. [SMP-03V-BC](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSM.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option you have that may very well be time convenient for you, especially if this project is a one-off type thing or low volume, is to cut off the unknown connector and crimp on new contacts and install a connector body of the type of something you already use. There are a plethora of different connectors you could use for this type of application.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually going to do that for several reasons even if I learn which type of connector it is. But it was just surprising that they would give connectors with no information anywhere on the net about which type of connector it is?